# Laravel Cancel Creation of Object

Tags: laravel, events

I have a Laravel app which has an object, Position, which is created via a form.

```
class Position extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'creating' => PositionCreating::class,
    ];
```

And this calls an event of the PositionCreating class, which I've tested, and is correctly firing. The underlying code also works to give me success or fail criteria.

```
class PositionCreating
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public function __construct(Position $position)
{
    if (some_good_stuff())
    {
    //keep creating the object
    } else {
    //stop creating the object
    }
}
```

If it works, that's fine, I just let the __construct() function finish executing and everything, including the pre-execution code I want, works perfectly.

But I don't know how to actually stop the creation of the object. I can, of course use the dd() function or something (which works and stops creation of the object as expected), but I want to present a readable error to the user in a friendly manner. What function or commands should I be using to cancel the creation of the object to return back to my position.create method?

Comment: Did you try throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes, which worked, but I don't want to completely kill exeution of the script, rather return or redirect back to the form just like Laravel's Validation works.

I can throw a return redirect() command but then the line gets inserted and it redirects anyway, where I want the create event to not fire.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but this is a way to do it. Models  fire several events. The one you're looking for is probably the "created" event. Each model event receive an instance of the model so you could just attach an event on your model, just like this:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => PositionCreated::class,
];
```

Inside your "PositionCreated" event, add a public property to get the model instance,like this:

```
 public $position;
 public function __construct(Position $position)
 {
      $this->position=$position; 
 }
```

Finally just add the logic on your "handle" method inside your event listener.

```
public function handle($event)
{
    if($something)
    {
        $event->position->delete();
    }
}
```

This should do the work.You can check for the other [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) and see wich one suits you the most.